# aws_s3.query_export_to_s3 PostgreSQL RDS extension exporting all multi-part CSV files to S3 with a header

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-aurora

I'm using the [`aws_s3.query_export_to_s3`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html) function to export data from an Amazon Aurora Postgresql database to S3 in CSV format with a header row.

This works.

However, when the export is large and outputs to multiple part files, the first part file has the CSV header row, and subsequent part files do not.

```sql
SELECT * FROM aws_s3.query_export_to_s3(
  'SELECT ...',
  aws_commons.create_s3_uri(...),
  options:='format csv, HEADER true'
);
```

How can I make this export add the header row to all CSV file parts?

I'm using Apache Spark to load this CSV data and it expects a header row in each individual part file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make this export add the header row to all part filess?

It's not possible, unfortunately.

The `aws_s3.query_export_to_s3` function uses the PostgreSQL [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) command under the hood & then chunks the files appropriately depending on size.

Unless the extension picks up on the `HEADER true` option, caches the header & then provides an option to apply that to every CSV file generated, you're out of luck.

The expectation is that the files are then combined at destination when downloaded *or* the file processor has some mechanism of reading files in parts *or* the file processor only needs the header once.

Answer (score 0):

[I think you can do this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html#aws_s3.export_query_to_s3#postgresql-s3-export-examples), it's just a different query with the options format field

```
SELECT aws_s3.query_export_to_s3(
    'SELECT * from users’,
    '(my_bucket,some_path/file_name,us-west-2)'
    '(format csv)',
);
```

note that `'(my_bucket,some_path/file_name,us-west-2)'` is just the string output of a method like `aws_commons.create_s3_uri`